# How to use 128x128 icon for alt-tab in Linux?

Tags: linux, gtk, icons, gnome-3

I have a problem to show high quality icon in Alt-Tab in Linux. My development is using GTK2, and using gtk_window_set_icon() for a 128x128 png icon. And the environment is GNOME3.

However, when I alt-tab, the icon is blurred and pixelated.

I am not sure it is caused by GNOME3 freedesktop.org specification, or caused by GTK2. Please help.

Comment: Not specific to Linux, *BSD and Nexenta/Solaris would behave similarly with Gnome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install multiple versions of the icon, at different resolutions, and Gnome should pick the best one depending on the context. So for example on Fedora 15 the firefox package installs several icons:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/firefox.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/firefox.png
```

You can even install a scalable icon, so if it wanted to (it currently doesn't), the firefox package could install:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/firefox.svg
```

Then in the desktop file for the application just give the name of the icon, for example:

```
Icon=firefox
```

and Gnome should work it all out and choose the best icon for each context where it is using it.

Comment: Thank you. I think I miss the desktop file part. I would try about it sooner or later.

Comment: I don't know what is the reason, but only /usr/share/pixmaps/myapplication.png works in my case. I tried to use the png file in 16x16, 22x22, 24x24, 32x32, 128x128, none of the work.

Comment: When I try to paste png in these folders its giving me access denied. Any way to fix this without `sudo nautilus`? Because I'm using `Qt` in KaOSx.

Comment: @Noitidart Hi, that folder has got permissions that require elevated privileges. You can run other file browsers as root too, as `su -c file-browser-command` or you can change the permissions on the folder from the command line with `chmod o+=w /usr/share/icons/...`. Note that chmod also needs root privileges.

Comment: Thank you @nus for your feedback I'll test it out and let you know how it goes. :) Im trying to do things without `sudo` though so looking for `sudo`-less alternatives. :)